# How long should one wait to eat after exercise

Tags: exercise

I read some articles which claim that after each workout, we should have at least one hour's rest before meal; others suggest half an hour. Otherwise, it will do damage to one's stomach. These were in Chinese; I haven't found any English articles talking about this.

Does having a meal shortly after workout cause any harm to one's stomach? If so, what is the time period one should wait before eating?

Comment: Welcome Lance!  I edited to guide you on the site format.  This question may have been answered, please look at our previous quesitons....

Comment: Do you have links to the articles that have these claims? I am not aware of reasons to delay eating in healthy individuals, and in fact, there is evidence that for certain styles of workouts (such as long endurance), there is benefit to immediate consumption of calories in specific proportions.

Comment: That would be big news to cyclists and long-distance runners who frequently eat _while_ cycling/running and suffer no harm from it.

Comment: Before exercise seems different from after exercise.

Comment: @BryanKrause - That question specifically addresses eating and then exercising. This is exercising and then eating. They are separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really aren't any known harmful effects for an otherwise healthy person to eat directly after an exercise session. You may not have as much appetite, as the body will somewhat shut down the digestive system and redirect blood and other resources to more needed places in the body, but it is not actively harmful.

In actuality, there are quite a few studies now showing that an immediate feeding after exercise can both help lessen some of the effects of the exercise and promote greater muscle growth and adaptation. It used to be known as the "golden hour". Endurance athletes benefit from a drink that is 3:1 ration of carbs to protein, while power/strength athletes do better with an immediate ingestion of protein, and then more protein spaced every 3-4 hours throughout the day.

Here are a few supporting positions and studies:

[International Society of Sports Nutrition](https://jissn.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12970-017-0189-4) - Position paper.

[Physiological Society](https://physoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1113/jphysiol.2012.244897%4010.1002/%28ISSN%291469-445X%28CAT%29VirtualIssues%28VI%29VirtualIssue2016) - Immediate ingestion of protein stimulates protein synthesis

[Journal Nutritional Science/Vitaminology](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jnsv1973/45/4/45_4_401/_article/-char/ja/) - Immediate feeding promotes greater muscle mass and lower fat tissue in rats.

Answer (score -1):

Well it really doesnt matter. Mostly it depends on the workout and the objective of your workout and more importantly what you are eating after workout.

You seriously dont want to eat a burger or any fast food item after any kind f workout. A protein shake will do fine though.

If you are building muscle and doing workout to  grow your body then you must have a meal within 45 minutes of the workout.

Even if you are reducing your body fat or muscle the body needs carbohydrates in order to retain the energy lost during the workout.

Overall, it is never bad or effects of your health or stomach it really depends on what you are feeding your body.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalScience.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].